# Android Java: How to let your app remember an answer

Tags: java, android, xml, database

I'm making a quiz application on my android phone, and I am struggling with a problem for a long time now, cause I don't know how to continue. The goal of my quiz-app is to let the user listen to a sound and guess what's the name of it. So you have to type your answer in a text box. If you type the wrong answer you can try it again. If you type the right answer the app must remember that you typed the right answer. So if you finished a question and you will later return to that question page, you will see the right answer you typed.

My application can check the answer you typed, but my question is do you have to make a whole database to let the app remember your answer? And is that possible on an application?

I hope someone can help me with my problem, cause I'm not that familiar with java and making apps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use the SharedPreferences for this.

Just save a boolean to mark the question as answered.
Example:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
preferences.edit().putBoolean("Question_ID", true).commit();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Comment: But if you close the app and open it later will the app still rememember you did answer that question?

Comment: @JustvanTil, yes, that's what SharedPreferences are for.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options for storage on Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

If you have a large amount of quiz questions then it is no question that you should use SQLite.

However, if you have a smaller number of questions, then storing data as CSV into a file or using SharedPreferences might be a minimum viable solution to get you on your way to a functional app.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I'll make a pretty large amount of questions so I do have to have a database as you said. The fact is that I'm not familiar with databases in apps. Is it possible to define a variable for every question and let that change into "1" (finished) and "0" (unfinished)  ?

Comment: Yes, you can even store values as true or false (which is essentially stored as 1 or 0).

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

You can use a simple file, shared preferences, or a database.  Read the page linked above.  It has everything you need including sample code and great explanations.

Answer (score 0):

If your questions are ordered - and they should be, even if you're randomly presenting them, since you read them from some stream or have  them in some array when your app starts - then the user's answers can take this same order, and your program's question of "did the user get this right?" (as well as many other useful questions that quizzing software might ask of itself) is answered this simply: what # question is this, internally? Oh, it's 42. So is userGotItRight[42] true or false?

userGotItRight[] is a boolean array, something you can effortlessly persist in a single SharedPreference.

You don't need SQL. You sure don't need a 1:1 map of questions to SharedPreference keys.  As your program evolves you can store an evolved serializable object array instead of a boolean array, or you might have a preference per question bank.